# How to find the probability that the second card drawn from a deck is a face card, given that the first card drawn was a queen

Tags: probability

If two cards are drawn at random without replacement from a standard deck, find the probability that the second card is a face card, given that the first card was a queen.

A. 3/13

B. 4/17

C. 11/51

D. 5/17

I tried doing $13/52 \cdot 12/51$, $4/52 \cdot 3/51$, and $26/52 \cdot 25/51$, but none of the solutions to these three calculations matched the choices provided.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for welcoming me. I tried doing 13/52 * 12/51, 4/52 * 3/51, and 26/52 * 25/51, but none of the solutions to these three calculations matched the choices provided.

Comment: See the answer by KaYaNa.  What matters here is that once a queen has been drawn, only $11$ of the $51$ cards that remain in the deck are face cards.  The face cards are the four jacks, four queens, and four kings.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you. That's what I put as my answer and was not sure if it was correct.

Answer (score 3):

C. 11/51
As there are originally 52 cards in total 12 of which are face. If a queen has been drawn then this reduces the total number of cards to 51 and the number of face cards to 11. The probability of pulling a face card now is 11/51.